# Google OR-Tools: CVRP with multiple cargo types and capacities

Tags: or-tools

I am trying to solve a CVRP with multiple cargo types and capacities. Let's imagine I have four vehicles and two types of freight (oranges and apples). Each Vehicle do have different capacities for apples and oranges and every node have different a demand. Two vehicles are only able to transport apples and two are only able to transport oranges. So I defined the following data:

```
    data['demands_oranges'] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8]
    data['demands_apples'] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8]
    data['vehicle_capacities_oranges'] = [0, 0, 40, 40]
    data['vehicle_capacities_apples'] = [40, 40, 0, 0]
```

Also, I Defined two dimensions for each capacity:

```
    # Add Capacity constraint.
    def demand_callback_apples(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands_apples'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index_apples = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback_apples)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index_apples,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities_apples'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity_apples')

    def demand_callback_oranges(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands_oranges'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index_oranges = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback_oranges)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index_oranges,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities_oranges'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity_oranges')
```

The Probem is, that no solution is returned for this input data. Despite the fact that the vehicle capacity is not even close to be exceeded.
The Model works for some reason when I use:

```
data['vehicle_capacities_oranges'] = [0, 0, 40, 40]
data['vehicle_capacities_apples'] = [0, 0, 40, 40]
```

But that's not what I need. What is the reason for that?

Code:

```
    """Capacited Vehicles Routing Problem (CVRP)."""

from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp


def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = [
        [
            0, 548, 776, 696, 582, 274, 502, 194, 308, 194, 536, 502, 388, 354,
            468, 776, 662
        ],
        [
            548, 0, 684, 308, 194, 502, 730, 354, 696, 742, 1084, 594, 480, 674,
            1016, 868, 1210
        ],
        [
            776, 684, 0, 992, 878, 502, 274, 810, 468, 742, 400, 1278, 1164,
            1130, 788, 1552, 754
        ],
        [
            696, 308, 992, 0, 114, 650, 878, 502, 844, 890, 1232, 514, 628, 822,
            1164, 560, 1358
        ],
        [
            582, 194, 878, 114, 0, 536, 764, 388, 730, 776, 1118, 400, 514, 708,
            1050, 674, 1244
        ],
        [
            274, 502, 502, 650, 536, 0, 228, 308, 194, 240, 582, 776, 662, 628,
            514, 1050, 708
        ],
        [
            502, 730, 274, 878, 764, 228, 0, 536, 194, 468, 354, 1004, 890, 856,
            514, 1278, 480
        ],
        [
            194, 354, 810, 502, 388, 308, 536, 0, 342, 388, 730, 468, 354, 320,
            662, 742, 856
        ],
        [
            308, 696, 468, 844, 730, 194, 194, 342, 0, 274, 388, 810, 696, 662,
            320, 1084, 514
        ],
        [
            194, 742, 742, 890, 776, 240, 468, 388, 274, 0, 342, 536, 422, 388,
            274, 810, 468
        ],
        [
            536, 1084, 400, 1232, 1118, 582, 354, 730, 388, 342, 0, 878, 764,
            730, 388, 1152, 354
        ],
        [
            502, 594, 1278, 514, 400, 776, 1004, 468, 810, 536, 878, 0, 114,
            308, 650, 274, 844
        ],
        [
            388, 480, 1164, 628, 514, 662, 890, 354, 696, 422, 764, 114, 0, 194,
            536, 388, 730
        ],
        [
            354, 674, 1130, 822, 708, 628, 856, 320, 662, 388, 730, 308, 194, 0,
            342, 422, 536
        ],
        [
            468, 1016, 788, 1164, 1050, 514, 514, 662, 320, 274, 388, 650, 536,
            342, 0, 764, 194
        ],
        [
            776, 868, 1552, 560, 674, 1050, 1278, 742, 1084, 810, 1152, 274,
            388, 422, 764, 0, 798
        ],
        [
            662, 1210, 754, 1358, 1244, 708, 480, 856, 514, 468, 354, 844, 730,
            536, 194, 798, 0
        ],
    ]
    data['demands_oranges'] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8]
    data['demands_apples'] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8]

    data['vehicle_capacities_oranges'] = [0, 0, 40, 40]
    data['vehicle_capacities_apples'] = [0, 0, 40, 40]

    data['price_per_km'] = [1, 1, 1, 1]
    data["price_per_stop"] = [1, 1, 1, 1]
    data['num_vehicles'] = 4
    data['depot'] = 0

    return data


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    for capacity_ID in ['demands_oranges','demands_apples']:
        print("____Capacity_{}_____".format(capacity_ID))
        total_distance = 0
        total_load = 0
        for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
            index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
            plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
            route_distance = 0
            route_load = 0
            while not routing.IsEnd(index):
                node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)
                route_load += data[str(capacity_ID)][node_index]
                plan_output += ' {0} Load({1}) -> '.format(node_index, route_load)
                previous_index = index
                index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
                route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                    previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
            plan_output += ' {0} Load({1})\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                     route_load)
            plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
            plan_output += 'Load of the route: {}\n'.format(route_load)
            print(plan_output)
            total_distance += route_distance
            total_load += route_load
        print('Total distance of all routes: {}m'.format(total_distance))
        print('Total load of all routes: {}'.format(total_load))



def main():
    """Solve the CVRP problem."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    ### Kosten  festlegen ###
    def create_cost_callback(dist_matrix, km_costs, stop_costs):
        # Create a callback to calculate distances between cities.

        def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            return int(dist_matrix[from_node][to_node]) * (km_costs) + (stop_costs)

        return distance_callback

    for i in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        cost_callback = create_cost_callback(data['distance_matrix'], data["price_per_km"][i],
                                             data["price_per_stop"][i])  # Callbackfunktion erstellen
        cost_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(cost_callback)  # registrieren
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(cost_callback_index, i)  # Vehicle zuordnen


    # Add Capacity constraint.
    def demand_callback_apples(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands_apples'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index_apples = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback_apples)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index_apples,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities_apples'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity_apples')

    def demand_callback_oranges(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands_oranges'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index_oranges = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback_oranges)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index_oranges,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities_oranges'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity_oranges')


    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(10)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
    print(solution)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All location can only be visited **once**

So if you have `apples` **and** `oranges` you should duplicate the location instead, so one will be visited by one vehicle and one by an other vehicle...

note: When you change your capacity so a vehicle can carry both types then it works